# I can't play audio using the method var audio=new Audio("Audio track"); audio.play()

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm new to java script and whenever i'm trying to play an audio file using Java Script i get the error saying that:

1. Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
2. Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.

Please if someone can help me. My java script file is as below.

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var audio = new Audio("C:\Users\User\Web_Developement\Drum Kit\sounds\crash.mp3");
    audio.play();
  })
}
```

And also my index.html file.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Drum Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <h1 id="title">Drum  Kit</h1>
  <div class="set">
    <button class="w drum">w</button>
    <button class="a drum">a</button>
    <button class="s drum">s</button>
    <button class="d drum">d</button>
    <button class="j drum">j</button>
    <button class="k drum">k</button>
    <button class="l drum">l</button>
  </div>


  <footer>
    Made with ❤️ in London.
  </footer>
</body>
<script src="C:\Users\User\Web_Developement\Drum Kit\index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: You should set up a web server(like wamp), there are a lot of things that just doesn't work when dealing with local files

Comment: Do yourself a favor and run a local server. Running off the file protocol is not the best thing to do in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

Using the relative path to the audio source file worked for me:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var audio = new Audio("sounds/crash.mp3");
    audio.play();
  })
}
```

This is because a javascript instance running in the browser isn't meant to access the user's local files. You can avoid this kind of error by running your website from a local webserver to make a proper separation of server side files and client side files when testing and trying to use only relative paths.